# Cannot insert date into the Oracle databe in Spring Boot via Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, oracle11g, thymeleaf

I have a typo in my CRUD process. I couldn't handle with inserting date type into the my database named for Oracle 11g.

When I try to insert data, there is an error appeared on the console.

```
Field error in object 'employee' on field 'registerDate': rejected value [2019-09-11]; codes [typeMismatch.employee.registerDate,typeMismatch.registerDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.registerDate,registerDate]; arguments []; default message [registerDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'registerDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Temporal @javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date] for value '2019-09-11'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

How can I fix it?

Employee Forum

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/employees/save}"
                         th:object="${employee}" method="POST">
...

<input type="date" name="date" th:field="*{registerDate}"
                    class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Register Date">

</form>
```

Employee Object

```
@NotNull(message="is required")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="REGISTER_DATE")
private Date registerDate;
```

Controller Class

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee theEmployee,@RequestParam("date") String date) throws IOException, ParseException {

   // Date
   SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   Date registerDate = dateformat.parse(String.valueOf(date));

   System.out.println("/save | registerDate : " + registerDate);

   theEmployee.setRegisterDate(registerDate); 

   // save the employee
   employeeService.save(theEmployee);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to format the date for Oracle, for example:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm aa")
@Column(name = "date_start")
private Date dateStart;
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Date type is defined like 12.09.2019 in Thymeleaf part because of input date type. It throws a typo shown Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type java.util.Date] for value '2019-09-12'